# How do I get parent and nested values using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to extract categories and subcategories from a HTML page. The html looks like this:

```
<a class='menuitem submenuheader' href='#'>Beverages</a><div class='submenu'><ul><li><a href='productlist.aspx?parentid=053&catid=055'>Juice</a></li></ul></div><a class='menuitem submenuheader' href='#'>DIY</a><div class='submenu'><ul><li><a href='productlist.aspx?parentid=007&catid=052'>Miscellaneous</a></li><li><a href='productlist.aspx?parentid=007&catid=047'>Sockets</a></li><li><a href='productlist.aspx?parentid=007&catid=046'>Spanners</a></li><li><a href='productlist.aspx?parentid=007&catid=045'>Tool Boxes</a></li></ul></div><a class='menuitem submenuheader' href='#'>Electronics</a><div class='submenu'><ul><li><a href='productlist.aspx?parentid=003&catid=019'>Audio/Video</a></li><li><a href='productlist.aspx?parentid=003&catid=027'>Cameras</a></li><li><a href='productlist.aspx?parentid=003&catid=023'>Cookers</a></li><li><a href='productlist.aspx?parentid=003&catid=024'>Freezers</a></li><li><a href='productlist.aspx?parentid=003&catid=025'>Kitchen Appliances</a></li><li><a href='productlist.aspx?parentid=003&catid=048'>Measuring Instruments</a></li><li><a href='productlist.aspx?parentid=003&catid=020'>Microwaves</a></li><li><a href='productlist.aspx?parentid=003&catid=050'>Miscellaneous</a></li><li><a href='productlist.aspx?parentid=003&catid=026'>Personal Care</a></li><li><a href='productlist.aspx?parentid=003&catid=021'>Refrigerators</a></li><li><a href='productlist.aspx?parentid=003&catid=018'>TV</a></li><li><a href='productlist.aspx?parentid=003&catid=022'>Washers/Dryers/Vacuum Cleaners</a></li></ul></div>
```

Where Beverage is the category and Juice is the subcategory.

I have the following code working to extract the category:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2


url = "http://www.myprod.com"

def main():
  response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
  html = response.read()

  soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
  categories = soup.findAll("a", {"class" :'menuitem submenuheader'})
  for cat in categories:
    print cat.contents[0]
```

How would I get the subcategory in this format?

```
[Beverages = Category]
 [Juice = Sub]
[DIY = Category]
 [Miscellaneous = Sub]
 [Spanners = Sub]
 [Sockets = Sub]
[Electronics]
 [Audio = Sub]
 [Cameras]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From each category html you have to find the next element and from there find it's li elements:

```
print cat.findNext().findAll('li')
```

Comment: this works to some extent but it gives me all of the nested values, instead of on a per category structure.
[Category=Juice]
 [Sub=MinuteMaid]
[Category=Electronics]
  [Sub=Blenders]

Comment: Then the page is not very nicely made. Use `findNext()` instead of `findParent()` .

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your html always have those *submenu* divs, it's probably better to return one list for the categories and another for the subcategories in a way that `cats[i]` corresponds to `subcats[i]` or, depending on what you want, return a dictionary.

In the Python shell:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '''<a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="#">Beverages</a>
... <div class="submenu">
...  <ul>
...   <li><a href="productlist.aspx?parentid=053&amp;catid=055">Juice</a></li>
...   <li><a href="productlist.aspx?parentid=053&amp;catid=055">Milk</a></li>
...  </ul>
... </div>
... <a class="menuitem submenuheader" href="#">DIY</a>
... <div class="submenu">
...  <ul>
...   <li><a href="productlist.aspx?parentid=053&amp;catid=055">Micellaneous</a></li>
...   <li><a href="productlist.aspx?parentid=053&amp;catid=055">Spanners</a></li>
...   <li><a href="productlist.aspx?parentid=053&amp;catid=055">Sockets</a></li>
...  </ul>
... </div>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> categories = soup.findAll("a", {"class": 'menuitem submenuheader'})
>>> cats = [cat.text for cat in categories]
>>> sub_menus = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "submenu"})
>>> subcats = []
>>> for menu in sub_menus:
...     subcat = [item.text for item in menu.findAll('li')]
...     subcats.append(subcat)
... 
>>> print cats
[u'Beverages', u'DIY']
>>> print subcats
[[u'Juice', u'Milk'], [u'Micellaneous', u'Spanners', u'Sockets']]
>>> cat_dict = dict(zip(cats,subcats))
>>> print cat_dict
{u'Beverages': [u'Juice', u'Milk'], u'DIY': [u'Micellaneous', u'Spanners', u'Sockets']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the webpage in question, it looks like all the newstories are in `h3` tags with the class `item-heading`. You can use BeautifulSoup to select all the story headers and then step upwards to access the `a href` that they are wrapped in:

```
In [54]: [i.parent.attrs["href"] for i in soup.select('a > h3.item-heading')]
Out[55]:
[{'href': '/news/us-news/civil-rights-groups-fight-trump-s-refugee-ban-uncertainty-continues-n713811'},
 {'href': '/news/us-news/protests-erupt-nationwide-second-day-over-trump-s-travel-ban-n713771'},
 {'href': '/politics/politics-news/some-republicans-criticize-trump-s-immigration-order-n713826'},
...  # trimmed for readability
]
```

I've used a list comprehension but you could split out into the composite steps:

```
# select all `h3` tags with the matching class that are contained within an `a` link.
# This excludes any random links elsewhere on the page.
story_headers = soup.select('a > h3.item-heading')

# Iterate through all the matching `h3` items and access their parent `a` tag.
# Then, within the parent you have access to the `href` attribute.
list_of_links = [i.parent.attrs for i in story_headers]

# Finally, extract the links into a tidy list
links = [i["href"] for i in list_of_links]
```

Once you have the list of links, you could iterate through it to check whether the first character is a `/` to match only local links and not external links.